# Jackson only sees hibernate PersistentSet and not the actual Set

Tags: hibernate, jackson

I have a set of domain classes that are using hibernate for persistence. This is working fine. But now I'm trying to implement XML/JSON marshalling on top of this, and I have some problems with Jackson and Sets it seems.

So my code is basically this:

```
@XmlRootElement
class IdentifiableObject {
  @XmlAttribute
  Integer id;

  @XmlElement
  String name;
}

@XmlRootElement
class A extends IdentifiableObject {}

@XmlRootElement
class B extends IdentifiableObject {
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "aSet")
  @XmlJavaAdapter( IdentifiableXmlAdapter.class )
  @XmlElement( name = "a" )
  Set<A> As;
}
```

This works fine in JAXB (which I am also using), but trying to marshall this using Jackson (using JaxbAnnotationIntrospector) I get this exception:

```
Unable to marshal: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to IdentifiableObject (through reference chain: B["aSet"])
```

So it seems the jackson marshaller sees the hibernate proxy, and not the actual bean.. but JAXB uses this fine.

My webview is using the filter org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter which makes sure that the hibernate session is opened (and reused).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

UPDATE: So it actually seems that if I remove the @XmlJavaAdapter from the set, it works on the jackson side.. but I need to rewrite my object since it actually has a cyclic reference. Why would @XmlJavaAdapter mess the type up here? and only with Jackson?

--
Morten

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions: first of all, by default Jackson does not use JAXB annotations so you may need to enable support (Jackson has its own set of annotations that work better; JAXB support is aimed at legacy systems).

But beyond this, specific support for Hibernate types is provided via [Jackson Hibernate module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate), so you probably want to add that. It can handle lazy references as well as proxy types.

Finally, Jackson has some support for dealing with specific kinds of cyclic dependencies (of parent/child type common with relational models), see [this blog entry](http://jackson-users.ning.com/profiles/blogs/using-bidirectional-feature) for more.

Comment: Yes, I have actually enabled both using the pairing AnnotationIntrospector (Jackson first, then JAXB). I did not know about the hibernate module, I will look into it.

Comment: Btw, I kinda solved it using a JsonSerializer, it will get the proper object and I just do a custom object using the jgen. I was hoping to use jgen.writeObject( ... ) but even if I downcast to IdentifiableObject it still marshalls the old value.

Comment: Ok, glad it works. Can always file a bug, too, against hibernate module or jackson proper